# How to correct time in ubuntu?

Tags: windows-8, time

I have two systems: Ubuntu and Windows 8.1. When I change the system from Windows to Ubuntu I have no problem with system time but when I change the system from Ubuntu to Windows the time is always increased for 3 hours. What is my problem? Thanks

Also, in Ubuntu it looks:

[image]

And in the additional panel:

[image]

But as result we can see ("Rainy River") on the left top:

[image]

Comment: Is the time-zone set the same on both systems?

Comment: I have seen and It seems I have two times installed in Ubuntu: manual and automatic. I cannot exclude one of them